# Transforming data frame to a selection list in selectInput (Shiny)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, shiny

I've a data frame corresponding to the sample below:

```
df = data.frame(subject=c("Subject A", "Subject B", "Subject C", "Subject D"),id=c(1:4))
```

I would like to transform this data frame to a list object that could be conveniently implemented in `selectInput`:

```
selectInput("subject", "Subject",
            choices = #my_new_list )
```

*I would like for the end-user to see the list of subjects in the selection and for the `selectInput` to return the corresponding numerical value (`id`).*

If I attempt to get my list via:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- as.list(df)
```

The `selectInput` drop down menu shows all available options:

[image: Select Input Preview]

I'm only interested in listing subjects and passing the corresponding numerical values.

Comment: I am not sure about the structure you want to get. Maybe `split(df$id, df$subject)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use function `split`:

```
my_new_list <- split(df$id, df$subject)
my_new_list
#$`Subject A`
#[1] 1

#$`Subject B`
#[1] 2

#$`Subject C`
#[1] 3

#$`Subject D`
#[1] 4
```

Together with function `with`:

```
my_new_list <- with(df, split(id, subject))
```

Answer (score 3):

For the `choices` argument, you can use a named list, from the doc:

> If elements of the list are named then that name rather than the value
>   is displayed to the user

To make the named list you could try:

```
your_choices <- as.list(df$id)
names(your_choices) <- df$subject
```

And in the app:

```
selectInput("subject", "Subject",
                choices = your_choices )
```

Comment: this answer is an absolute jackpot. worked great for me. Tks NicE

Answer (score 0):

Use `setNames`, for example:

`selectizeInput('x3', 'X3', choices = setNames(state.abb, state.name))`

like in this example http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/option-groups-for-selectize-input.html