# R shiny load data.frame for selectInput

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am trying to write a shiny app that loads several data frames. The data frames for my plots all work very well, but one data.frame which I want to use as a list of options in a dropdown menu does not load. If I load the frame seperately in the R session, everything works, but if I only run the shiny app, the selectors won't update.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
               #...
               selectInput("mats", "Text",
                           selectors)
               # ...
)

server <- function(input, output){
     # ...
     df1=read.csv("./data/file.csv", sep=";", head=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
     df1$choices=as.character(df1$choices)
     selectors=c("All", df1$choices)
     #...
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I think, I need the selectors in the server function, so I loaded the data frame there together with my other data frames. Is that the right place and what do I need to do to get this running?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of problems with your code:

1. Following the documentation, `choices` in `selectInput` should be a list.
2. If you want to create an element that would be available across the `ui` and `server` please consider [reading the linked article on scoping rules in Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) and defining your object in `global.R`.

With respect to the **1st** point, if your intention is to use a `data.frame` column as a base for menu selection, you can apply the following transformation:

```
my_new_list <- split(df$id, df$subject)
```

as provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31204511/1655567) by **@user3710546** to [a similar question that I've asked in past.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31203985/1655567)

---

## Side note

Please consider having a look at [the discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1655567) on making a reproducible example in **R.** If you care to redo your example using some publicly available data, it will be easy to produce a solution. If I understood the problem correctly, you want to use `data.frame` column as a base for `UI` element, which is not difficult on its own.

.